# Add LEFT JOIN add MSSQL Server PDO pagination PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I currently do the pagination. I already create the pagination for only one table and success. Now, I want to create the paging with join another table which mean I want to use LEFT JOIN. below is my current code

```
 $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM ( SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Book_No) 
                as row FROM booking) a WHERE row between ".$offset." and ".$total_records_per_page."");
```

and I want to add Left Join same like this.

```
LEFT JOIN room ON booking.Room_ID = room.Room_ID WHERE Admin_email = '$Email'
```

can I know how to combine the query? Please help

Answer (score 0):

Nothing much needs to change:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Book_No) AS row
    FROM booking b
    LEFT JOIN room r
        ON b.Room_ID = r.Room_ID
    WHERE Admin_email = :email
) a
WHERE row BETWEEN :start AND :end;
```

Sample script:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Book_No) AS row
    FROM booking b
    LEFT JOIN room r
        ON b.Room_ID = r.Room_ID
    WHERE Admin_email = :email
) a
WHERE row BETWEEN :start AND :end";


$query = $conn->prepare($sql);
$query->execute([':email' => $email, 'start' => $offset,
    'end' => $total_records_per_page]);
```

Comment: which one i need to use based on your answer? the top or bottom one?

Comment: The bottom version just uses the query on top, that is all.

Comment: Undefined variable: email in C:\xampp\htdocs\ebooking\indes.php on line 151

and

Comment: he column 'Room_ID' was specified multiple times for 'a'.

Comment: I am assuming that you have a variable called `$email` in your script.  Obviously, if you _don't_, then the script would crash.